# Minimum volume doesn't mute in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, audio

When I reduce the volume down to its minimum in Windows 8, it doesn't mute, unlike Windows 7.

Is there any way to change this behavior back or no?

Comment: Windows 8 user here, just set my volume to 0. No sound.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Weird, I guess it's my computer then. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **manufacturing issue**. Muting and setting volume are two different commands for any sound card (including television). The reason is that it is cheaper to build a card that goes to volume < 0.01 instead of a card that completely mutes (because of the electricity). The more you can reduce the volume the more expensive the sound card becomes.

In other words: When you have 0 in your mixer, it means 0 amplifying, it doesn't mean you do not get any sound, it just means that it is not amplified. And that is where the mute button comes in.

**Update**: The only thing you can do is giving out money and buy some better hardware.

Comment: If it's a manufacturing issue how does it work fine in Windows 7?!

Comment: I do not know your exact setup. Maybe the Windows 7 architecture is different. But you can also detect that effect at television.

Comment: If the Windows 7 architecture makes a difference then it's not a hardware issue is it?

Comment: It could be both. You could set an amplifier with volume control between your computer and your speakers and set it to low volume.

Comment: I just checked it with my expensive setup and I have the same issue. Maybe you never checked it correctly with Windows 7.

Comment: I've been using Windows 7 for at least 2 years now and I'm 100% sure I've checked it correctly.

Comment: My television at 0 volume sends the same "static" electric noise as when muted. **For certain specific hardware** you *may* be right. But I think it's a fallacy to actually say that it **must be** a manufacturing issue without further details (we don't know the hardware/drivers the OP is using and he asserts that Win7 worked fine).